# Can an Android app use existing website functions, JavaScript methods, PHP scripts?

Tags: php, javascript, android, wordpress

I want to make an Android App and have already built the HTML website with Wordpress.  I was wondering...If I make an Android App can I get it to use the functions that I have already created for the website.. such as jQuery / javascript functions, php scripts, etc?

Comment: Basically no. But you could use a frame to load the website, but that requires an internet connection. PHP is a server side language so there is no way you'll be able to simply execute it on your phone, however there may exist some compilers for php on android.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `jQuery`/`javascript` functions, since these client side scripting and runs on user browsers. `PHP` script/functions runs on Server side and renders into `HTML` output.

There are some alternate ways that you can use to run php function via client side using `AJAX`.

look for following example:

```
function showHint(str){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP will contain your function with html output:

```
<?php
    // Fill up array with names
    $a[]="Anna";
    $a[]="Brittany";
    $a[]="Cinderella";
    $a[]="Diana";
    $a[]="Eva";
    $a[]="Fiona";
    $a[]="Gunda";
    $a[]="Hege";
    $a[]="Inga";
    $a[]="Johanna";
    $a[]="Kitty";
    $a[]="Linda";
    $a[]="Nina";
    $a[]="Ophelia";
    $a[]="Petunia";
    $a[]="Amanda";
    $a[]="Raquel";
    $a[]="Cindy";
    $a[]="Doris";
    $a[]="Eve";
    $a[]="Evita";
    $a[]="Sunniva";
    $a[]="Tove";
    $a[]="Unni";
    $a[]="Violet";
    $a[]="Liza";
    $a[]="Elizabeth";
    $a[]="Ellen";
    $a[]="Wenche";
    $a[]="Vicky";

    //get the q parameter from URL
    $q=$_GET["q"];

    //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
    if (strlen($q) > 0){
        $hint="";
        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
            if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q)))){
                if ($hint==""){
                    $hint=$a[$i];
                } else {
                    $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
    // or to the correct values
    if ($hint == ""){
        $response="no suggestion";
    } else {
        $response=$hint;
    }

    //output the response
    echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: So I can run php only if I use Ajax?  How do I link up the Android backend to use the php scripts from my server...and for the javascript for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout appmobi.com it basically allows you to write an app using html/javascript, and it compiles it for you and publishes it into the app store.  PHP won't run in the app itself, but you can use ajax to communicate with the server.  I have an app built through there that shows different athletes career stats, and every time the page loads I do an ajax call to my server to update the stats, as they change very time the athletes play a game.  Also check out phonegap, tiggzi and application craft.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cannot (and should not) execute PHP scripts on your mobile. PHP scripts are meant to be run on servers and not clients.

If you already have created a website (hosted on a server) and just want to open it in an android app, go for Webview (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). It will help you open up an existing link in the application.

If you are planning to create a native app containing your HTML and JavaScript, you can do that too. Basically you can open a local link in the webview, and also switch between local and server (php) links. Additionally you can use AJAX (use JQuery or JQuery mobile) to make server calls.

Additional two cents, if you are planning to go for HTML, JavaScript native app, I will suggest going for phonegap (http://phonegap.com/). Phonegap helps creating simple JavaScript/ HTML application, and also provides methods to call native phone functions like use of camera, dial a number etc. And the coolest part is, once you have an app in one platform (Android), you can easily create apps on other platforms like iOS, Blackberry , Windows mobile by reusing same code. Worth a try if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

It's Easy. You should use webview.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Hey Arno, I appreciate the answer bit I dont want to show the existing website, i want to create a custom app that allows me to use the scripts that the website is already using for the app.

Comment: Edited: You should use rss feed or your web site. Wordpress is fully support for rss feed.